# WiFi not working on hp envy dv6 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless

*HP envy dv6* will not connect to WiFi after I updated it. When it works, it works for 5 minutes or less.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 28 Feb 2015 12:33 EET +0200

Booted last: 28 Feb 2015 12:22 EET +0200

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-31-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 10 15:24:04 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, intel_pstate=disable

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 BGN [8086:4062]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

0b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1818]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:58d8 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0461:4d5f Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0018 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint scanner
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1058:1042 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 14109  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 hp_wmi
iwldvm                236430  0 
mac80211              660592  1 iwldvm
mxm_wmi                13021  0 
wl                   6367694  0 
iwlwifi               183038  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              510218  4 wl,iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
wmi                    19193  2 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fd08:7a4c:44e4:5a00:86a6:c8ff:fe87:6b76/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fd08:7a4c:44e4:5a00:6010:7bb3:af2a:9d66/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::86a6:c8ff:fe87:6b76/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6345 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6668 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3315621 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:1703647 (1.7 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"m7md shw2y 01015665625"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'm7md shw2y 01015665625' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=19.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:6  Invalid misc:33   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: <MAC address> ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Bluetooth
  Driver:            bluez
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no

  Capabilities:

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: wlan0  [m7md shw2y 01015665625] --------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           19 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *m7md shw2y 01015665625: Infra, <MAC 'm7md shw2y 01015665625' [AC1]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 45 WPA2
    mohamed2:        Infra, <MAC 'mohamed2' [AN2]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 97 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.5
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

  IPv6 Settings:
    Address:         fd08:7a4c:44e4:5a00:6010:7bb3:af2a:9d66
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         ::

    Address:         fd08:7a4c:44e4:5a00:86a6:c8ff:fe87:6b76
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         ::

    Address:         fe80::86a6:c8ff:fe87:6b76
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         ::

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>,

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ali]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ali | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ali | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Mohammad]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Mohammad | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Mohammad | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP]] (600 root)
[connection] id=AndroidAP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=AndroidAP | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/AndroidAP.VG3NTX]] (644 root)
[connection] id=AndroidAP | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=AndroidAP | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/m7md shw2y 01015665625]] (600 root)
[connection] id=m7md shw2y 01015665625 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=m7md shw2y 01015665625 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/LINKDSL-felimoon]] (600 root)
[connection] id=LINKDSL-felimoon | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=LINKDSL-felimoon | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/mohamed2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=mohamed2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=mohamed2 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Africa/Cairo (based on set time zone)

country EG: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 20), (N/A, 20)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 20), (N/A, 20), DFS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'm7md shw2y 01015665625' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"m7md shw2y 01015665625"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000012b41a05f2
                    Extra: Last beacon: 88ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     716426034C9E4259C23DEDA
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A1:12:C1:8A:44:8A:56:00:47:EF:1F:4D:B7:4D:49:7F:61:A4:50:99
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     D0CBADABD6F74A53B0BE7CC
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A1:12:C1:8A:44:8A:56:00:47:EF:1F:4D:B7:4D:49:7F:61:A4:50:99
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     DF2576C38AD45205B3556DD
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode
srcversion:     7F17406EFFE91762CB15EEE
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A1:12:C1:8A:44:8A:56:00:47:EF:1F:4D:B7:4D:49:7F:61:A4:50:99
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-31-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     88153DA7841870E4F2012EE
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A1:12:C1:8A:44:8A:56:00:47:EF:1F:4D:B7:4D:49:7F:61:A4:50:99
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211 options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x0887 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   21.796902] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   21.804697] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
[   22.049316] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   22.057079] iwlwifi 0000:0a:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x0-0x0
[   22.129589] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   23.359471] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'm7md shw2y 01015665625' [AC1]>
[   23.365286] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'm7md shw2y 01015665625' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   23.367166] wlan0: authenticated
[   23.367288] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'm7md shw2y 01015665625' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   23.371409] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'm7md shw2y 01015665625' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[   23.374169] wlan0: associated
[   23.374189] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-
what-can-i-do>

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10466083/ here is the link of the txt file ,,

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: just a small question from a fellow learner : why exactly 11n_disable=8 ? why not 11n_disable=1 ?